# Diferença entre Azure Queue e Service Bus Queue

Tags: microsoft-azure, cloud

Notei que o Microsoft Azure apresenta dois tipos de fila: Azure Queue que faz parte do Azure Storage e o Service Bus Queue. [Nesse tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-get-started/) do site do Azure utiliza-se o serviço Azure Queue pra troca de mensagens entre Web Role e Worker Role de um Cloud Service, já [nesse outro](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-multi-tier-app-using-service-bus-queues/) o Service Bus Queue que é usado.

Quais as diferenças entre os dos tipos de fila e em quais cenários cada um deve ser usado?

Answer (score 4):

[Esta página do MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh767287(VS.103).aspx) mostra detalhadamente as diferenças entre os dois tipos de fila (e são muitas - em relação a desempenho, capacidade, segurança, cotas, entre outros).

Basicamente, você deve usar o Azure Queue se:

- Seu aplicativo precisa armazenar o equivalente a mais de 80 GB de mensagens em uma fila, onde as mensagens têm um tempo de vida de menos de 7 dias.
- Seu aplicativo deseja rastrear o progresso para processar uma mensagem dentro da fila. Isso será útil se o trabalho que está processando uma mensagem falhar. Um trabalho subsequente pode então usar essas informações para continuar de onde o anterior parou.
- Você precisa de logs do servidor de todas as transações executadas em suas filas.

E você usaria o Service Bus Queue se:

- Sua solução deve ser capaz de receber mensagens sem precisar sondar a fila. Com o Service Bus, isso pode ser obtido com o uso da operação de recepção de sondagem longa via protocolos baseados em TCP ou protocolo que o Service Bus suporta.
- Sua solução requer a fila para fornecer uma entrega com ordenação FIFO (primeiro a entrar, primeiro a sair) garantida.
- Você quer uma experiência simétrica no Azure e no Windows Server (nuvem privada). Para obter mais informações, consulte Service Bus for Windows Server.
- Sua solução deve ser capaz de dar suporte à detecção automática de duplicidades.
- Você quer que seu aplicativo processe mensagens na forma de fluxos paralelos de execução longa (as mensagens são associadas a um fluxo usando a propriedade SessionId na mensagem). Neste modelo, cada nó no aplicativo de consumo compete por fluxos, e não por mensagens. Quando um fluxo é dado a um nó de consumo, o nó pode examinar o estado de fluxo do aplicativo usando transações.
- Sua solução requer comportamento transacional e atomicidade ao enviar ou receber várias mensagens de uma fila.
- A característica de TTL (vida útil) da carga de trabalho específica ao aplicativo pode exceder o período de 7 dias.
- Seu aplicativo manipula mensagens que podem exceder 64 KB, mas provavelmente não se aproximará do limite de 256 KB.
- Você lida com uma exigência de fornecer um modelo de acesso baseado em função às filas, e direitos/permissões diferentes para remetentes e destinatários.
- O tamanho da fila não ultrapassará 80 GB.
- Você quer usar o agente de mensagens com base em padrões AMQP 1.0. Para obter mais informações sobre AMQP, consulte Visão geral do AMQP do Service Bus.
- Você pode prever uma migração eventual da comunicação ponto a ponto baseada em fila para um padrão de troca de mensagens que permite a integração perfeita de destinatários adicionais (assinantes), cada um dos quais recebe cópias independentes de algumas ou de todas as mensagens enviadas à fila. O último se refere ao recurso de publicação/assinatura fornecido pelo Service Bus de forma nativa.
- Sua solução de mensagens deve ser capaz de dar suporte à garantia de entrega "no máximo uma vez" sem a necessidade de que você crie os componentes adicionais da infraestrutura.
- Você gostaria de poder publicar e consumir lotes de mensagens.
- Precisa de integração total com a pilha de comunicação do Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) no .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

As diferenças podem ser vistas na resposta enviada pelo Carlos Figueira. Falando no Service Bus Queue, ele permite uma comunicação unidirecional. Fornece um balanceamento de carga, onde mensagens são recebidas e processadas pelos receptores concorrentes na ordem em que foram adicionadas à uma mesma fila.
Movendo esse serviço para o Azure, os desenvolvedores podem trabalhar em aplicações distribuídas utilizando o sistema com foco em enfileiramento de mensagens. Assim, através da camada intermediária, uma aplicação cria e coloca uma mensagem na fila, enquanto outra aplicação processa e retorna a primeira da mesma forma (quando necessário).

Mais informações sobre o Azure Service Bus podem ser vistar em http://talkitbr.com/2015/06/19/azure-service-bus/